# Filter sublist record/s along with parent list field

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, data-filtering

I want to filter records which have `ModelLogin.LoginDate = dateTimeToday` and `ModelLoginRecords.LoginPurpose = "Update"`.

Result must be a `ModelLogin` list which have its `LoginDate(dateTimeToday)` and `LoginRecords` sublist which have `"Update"` only.

[image]

**Model 1**

```
public class ModelLogin
{
    public DateTime LoginDate;
    public List<ModelLoginRecords> LoginRecords;

    public ModelLogin(DateTime LoginDate, List<ModelLoginRecords> LoginRecords)
    {
        this.LoginDate = LoginDate;
        this.LoginRecords = LoginRecords;
    }
}
```

**Model 2**

```
public class ModelLoginRecords
{
    public string UserName;
    public string LoginPurpose;

    public ModelLoginRecords(string UserName, string LoginPurpose)
    {
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.LoginPurpose = LoginPurpose;
    }
}
```

**Sample data**

```
        List<ModelLogin> listLogins = new List<ModelLogin>();

        List<ModelLoginRecords> loginRecordsList = new List<ModelLoginRecords>();
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("Alex", "Update"));
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("David", "Update"));
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("Jason", "Remove"));
        listLogins.Add(new ModelLogin(dateTimeToday, loginRecordsList));

        loginRecordsList = new List<ModelLoginRecords>();
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("Kate", "Update"));
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("William", "Remove"));
        listLogins.Add(new ModelLogin(dateTimeYesterday, loginRecordsList));
```

Comment: What version of EF?  What have you tried? Have you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include ?

Comment: currently I'm not using Entity Framework and I want to filter hard coded list.

Comment: It would be best to include an example of your desired output in questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below.

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void test()
    {
        //arrange
        var updatePurpose = "Update";
        var removePurpose = "Remove";

        List<ModelLogin> listLogins = new();
        var dateTimeToday = DateTime.Today;
        var dateTimeYesterday = dateTimeToday.AddDays(-1);

        List<ModelLoginRecords> loginRecordsList = new();

        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("Alex", updatePurpose));
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("David", updatePurpose));
        loginRecordsList.Add(new ModelLoginRecords("Jason", removePurpose));
        listLogins.Add(new ModelLogin(dateTimeToday, loginRecordsList));

        loginRecordsList = new List<ModelLoginRecords>
        {
            new ModelLoginRecords("Kate", updatePurpose),
            new ModelLoginRecords("William", removePurpose)
        };
        listLogins.Add(new ModelLogin(dateTimeYesterday, loginRecordsList));

        //act
        var loginModelsWithUpdatePurpose = listLogins.Where(listLogin =>
            listLogin.LoginDate.Date == dateTimeToday.Date &&
            listLogin.LoginRecords.Any(i => i.LoginPurpose == updatePurpose)
        ).Select(i =>
            new ModelLogin(
                i.LoginDate,
                i.LoginRecords.Where(j => j.LoginPurpose == updatePurpose).ToList()
            )
        ).ToList();

        //assert
        foreach (var loginModel in loginModelsWithUpdatePurpose)
            Assert.DoesNotContain(loginModel.LoginRecords, i => i.LoginPurpose != updatePurpose);
    }
}

public class ModelLoginRecords
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string LoginPurpose { get; private set; }

    public ModelLoginRecords(string userName, string loginPurpose)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        LoginPurpose = loginPurpose;
    }
}

public class ModelLogin
{
    public DateTime LoginDate { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModelLoginRecords> LoginRecords { get; private set; }

    public ModelLogin(DateTime loginDate, IEnumerable<ModelLoginRecords> loginRecords)
    {
        LoginDate = loginDate;
        LoginRecords = loginRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same issue I'm facing. When using .LoginRecords.Any returns the list without excluding removePurpose.  if the subchild contains updatePurpose and if its parent also contains removePurpose gets all the bundle.

Comment: Any checks sublist contains updatePurpose or not; if contains returns whole parent list without excluding removePurpose

Comment: @AlexanderRaymak I've updated my answer, I recommed you to read more about LINQ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/